# Joint density given, calculate marginal probability

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X,Y)$ be a bivariate random variable with joint density $f_{X,Y}:\mathbf{R}^2\to\mathbf{R}$ given by
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}ye^{-y}, & 0<x<\frac1y<\infty \\ 0,& \text{elsewhere}.\end{cases}$$

Calculate $\mathbf{P}(X\leqslant 1)$.

---

My work:

$$\mathbf{P}(X\leqslant 1)=\int_1^\infty \int_0^{1/y} ye^{-y}\,dx\,dy=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{y}\cdot ye^{-y}\,dy=\int_1^\infty e^{-y}\,dy=\left[-e^{-y}\right]_1^\infty= \boxed{\frac{1}{e}}$$

since $x$ is inbetween $0$ and $\frac1y$, if we let $y$ vary from $1$ to $\infty$, we get $x$ inbetween $0$ and $1$.

However, the answer is supposed to be $1-\frac1e$. Below is the teacher's answer:

[image]

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Even if $Y\le 1$, you can have $X\le 1$ with nonzero probability, that is what you have not accounted for. To fix your calculation, you will need to add that as another integral where both $x$ and $y$ will vary in the range $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method would need to integrate over: $\{(x,y): 0<x<1, x<1/y\}$, which equals $\{(x,y): 0<x<1<1/y\}\cup\{(x,y):0< x<1/y<1\}$

$$\mathsf P(X\leq 1)~{=~\iint_{0<x<\min\{1,1/y\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d (x, y)\\=~\int_0^1 \int_0^{1} f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y+\int_1^\infty\int_0^{1/y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y}$$

---

The teacher's method relies on $\{(x,y): 1<x<1/y\}$ being an easier domain with whic to work.

$$\mathsf P(X\leq 1)~{=1-\mathsf P(X>1)\\=~1-\iint_{1<x<1/y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d (x, y)\\=~1-\int_0^1 \int_1^{1/y} f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y}$$

---